# allocation on the heap of 3d arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, function, loops

I'm trying to use nested for-loops and new, to write the C++ code that creates a 3x6x4 3D int array (with the name C) in the heap.

Heres my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
//#include "we.hh"

#define X 3
#define Y 6
#define Z 4

int main() {  

  //***<your_code_here>***
  int *** C;
  C = new int**[X * Y * Z];
  int i, j, k;

  for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    C[i] = new int*[X]; 

  for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
    C[i][j] = new int[Y];

  for (int k = 0; k < Z; k++) 
    C[i][j][k] = new int[Z];
```

I get an error on the last line saying invalid conversion from int* to int.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `C[i][j][k]` is an `int&`and `new int[Z]` returns an `int*`. What is unclear?

Comment: Btw, you have shadowing of variables and use `i` uninitialized in `C[i][j] = new int[Y];` and both `i` and `j` in `C[i][j][k] = new int[Z];`. The indentation of the program also "lies" but I edited the question to fix that.

Comment: You got a bad start with that `X * Y * Z`. Why would you need 72 `int**`s?

Comment: Note: This is way easier with `std::vector` and multi-dimensional array emulation. `new[]` is a rabbit hole filled with suffering.

Answer (score 1):

You're using C++ so don't use raw arrays or new.

```
std::array<std::array<std::array, Z>, Y>, X>   C;
```

done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest your loops not sequence them, you also have one too many loops, and you've allocated the wrong number of pointers at each level. Like this

```
int *** C = new int**[X];
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    C[i] = new int*[Y]; 
    for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
    {
        C[i][j] = new int[Z];
    }
}
```